# CSS Responsive way of positioning inline elements

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue to layout text around dash which should be in center with two different results expected.

**Html structure:**

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
   <span class="left">TEXT_ON_THE_LEFT</span>
   <span class="center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
   <span class="right">TEXT_ON_THE_RIGHT</span
</div>
```

**Example data:**

```
November 2016 - April 2017
May 2016 - November 2016
January 2016 - May 2016
```

**Result no 1:**

```
November 2016   -      April 2017
May 2016        -   November 2016
January 2016    -        May 2016
```

**Result no 2:**

```
 November 2016 - April 2017
      May 2016 - November 2016
  January 2016 - May 2016
```

How can I achieve two results above?

**Most important thing is** that we cannot specify fixed width to the left and right spans because they are contained in the parent element (wrapper) which has % width set depending on the screen size RWD (box-sizing: border-box)

Comment: You give a width for the left and right elements, and align the text in them the way you want ...

Comment: Is there a reason you are restricted to that mark up? It's more than do-able with the mark up you've provided, but ultimately this looks like table data to me.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @leighBicknell yes that would be easily done with table markup but there are plenty of such code snippets contained in separate parent elements and I thought that table element is simply too heavy for such purpose. Am I wrong ? What would you recommend me ?

Comment: @kkris1983 I reserve the use of table's for their intended purpose. Which is displaying data in a row/column format. Which is what this looks like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, create 3 spans with 3 different alignments, depending on what you need

```css
/* you need to set specific width to the block, so it knows the size of the 
 * block and how much it should align to the side. span's width is auto by 
 * default. Which would on human eye show no difference in text-align */
.lister {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

.left{
  text-align: left;
 }
 
.right {
  text-align: right;
 }
 
.center {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<span class="lister left">LEFT</span>
<span class="lister center">-</span>
<span class="lister right">RIGHT</span>
```

To play with the specific results/looks, simply lookup the `text-align` property. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align )

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to specify the width of left and right span especially the dash one which should contains only the character itself. The width of right and left spans is dependant of the parent div's width.

Comment: @kkris1983 and how would you imagine the align working, if it doesnt know to which width should it align the text to?? Just have the width of your elements add up to the width of the "parent" or simply use the `calc()` property to get it to be dependant on parent's width. Also if you don't want specific width to the dash, then simply don't assign it one...

Comment: that is why I was asking whether there is a solution for it so left and right spans dynamically occupy maximum width available in the wrapper around the dash being in the center without using javascript

Comment: @kkris1983 That was in no way incorporated into your original question. Furthermore, that's also what happens when you don't include jsfiddle for your other elements, then we're only left guessing. Either way, on how to achieve that dynamic sizing, just read my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was not being precise in giving description details. 
Thank you for your efford and help.
I have implemented solution based on the flexbox layout like this:

```css
.button{
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.wrapper > span{
  display: inline-block;
}

.left{
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.center{

}

.right{
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <span class="left">November 2016</span>
     <span class="center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
     <span class="right">April 2017</span>
  </div>
</button>
<!-- /* some unrelated markup */ -->

<button class="button">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <span class="left">May 2016</span>
     <span class="center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
     <span class="right">November 2016</span>
  </div>
</button>
<!-- /* some unrelated markup */ -->

<button class="button">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <span class="left">January 2016</span>
     <span class="center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
     <span class="right">May 2016</span>
  </div>
</button>
<!-- /* some unrelated markup */ -->
```